# How to design listview with contact avatar similarly to ICS GTalk or Messaging apps?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a listview whose items contain an avatar of a contact on the left side. In the remaining space, there are two rows of text, first contains the name of the person, the second contains email address (or whatever other text).

I would like to style the layout of the list item so that:

- The avatar image is on the leftmost side of the view. There is **no padding on the left** side.
- The height of the list item is determined only by the **height of the two lines of text**. The imageview has to **match this height**, no matter if the image is **larger or smaller**.
- There can be **no padding on the top or bottom** of the imageview.
- The imageview has to be **always square**, even if the image itself is rectangular. In such case, the image should be "zoomed" to fill the entire square, co it can be **cropped vertically or horizontally**, but the aspect ratio has to remain intact.

This is a screenshot from the ICS Messaging app, which meets all of these criteria:

[image]

I've read several SO threads involving `android:scaleType`, tried many combinations of `scaleType`, `adjustViewBounds` and `wrapContent`/`match_parent` settings, but I never got it right. Can anyone please help?

Here is some simplified XML layout that can serve as a starting point:

```
<!-- The avatar -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactImageView"
    android:layout_width="???"
    android:layout_height="???"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<!-- The 2-row textual layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactImageView"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First row -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Second row -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the width and height of the ImageView AND set the ScaleType to centerCrop you should have exactly what you want.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactImageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Where does the 50dp value come from? I would like the image to adjust its size to to textviews, not the other way around.

Comment: From nowhere, they're just examples: if your source images have different size and if you want ALL the avatars to have the same dimensions in your list, you must set those dimensions to your imageView.

Comment: Can't the image dimensions be derived from the size of the textviews? I don't like the idea of making up some random numbers very much. What if I change the global text size in the system?

Comment: If you get the height of a TextView with something like `Rect bounds;textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);` But then you have to account for padding as well. You would also have to deal with the possibility that not all TextView have the same height (some may have uppercase letters, some don't). Finally, you would have to set the width of you ImageView dimensions programmatically in your getView(). A lot of work, a lot of code, and not a big improvement IMHO given that it would rely on a fixed value for the font size anyway. I would go for a fixed value in the XML.